# How to use IN clause in Spring data Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I'm trying to query a Cassandra table using the IN clause and the @Query annotation from Spring Data

My query in init method-

```
     session = cassandraSessionFactory.getSession();
     statementmyList = session.prepare("select * from my_file_content where my_content IN (?);");
```

Tried to bind the query with boundStatement-

```
  final BoundStatement boundStatement = DaoConstants.getBoundStatement(statementmyList);

  try
  {
   List<Row> rowList =
      session
          .execute(
              boundStatement
                  .bind(myList))
          .all();

          // myList = "'04748558-0eb3','531aaf2bf6b782f95e2e','6fc98ac2'"     

}
```

rowList  returns empty Array. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't need the parenthesis if you are binding a full list, so it should be:

```java
session = cassandraSessionFactory.getSession();
statementmyList = session.prepare("select * from my_file_content where my_content IN ?;");
```

`(?)` would work if you were providing a single value, but you want `?` if you are providing a collection.

Comment: This is quite certain that okla wants to use a collection passed as param. Now I am querious to know if it works this way or not.

Comment: You can use a collection as a parameter, but you shouldn't have parenthesis around the bind marker, otherwise it will get interpreted as an element on a collection, instead of a collection itself.

Comment: Great, its a learning for me. I will try this out today.